# Custom Expandable List View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview

I am working with ExpandableListView in which I want to show following properties for the item in ListView

1. Grey image as a default background
2. Blue image when  item is clicked
3. White image when item is expanded

I have all the images with me, also I am able to achieve the first two things, but I am not able to understand how to change the image when that particular child is expanded. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: http://android-adda.blogspot.com/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by some R & D I got it working. What I did is set first two things from xml and for the last thing I did this in getGroupView()

```
if( isExpanded ){
            convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.settings_background2 );
        }
```

if some one has any other answer, please let me know :)